# Pandas mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay' not working

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

Even using the code below, the content on each sheet of the .xlsx file is overwritten, not appended. What is missing?

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excelfilepath, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Núcleo de TRIAGEM')

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Núcleo de FALÊNCIAS')

df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RE - Triagem')

df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RE - Falências')

writer.save()
```

Comment: any luck with this issue? did you manage to solve this? can you help me? I also encounter the same issue.

Comment: No solution yet @TheGreat. I made a comearound, reading the entire excel file, adding the new data and than overwritting the excel file.

Comment: I have an issue with excel file reading and writing using python - Would you be able to help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557677/xlwings-enter-data-in-a-excel-cell-only-when-it-matches-with-df-row-and-col

Comment: any luck for this issue?

Comment: see my answer, this is on purpose, you have to use startrow to insert below the existing data

Answer (score 8):

I know this is not typical, and most likely will be fixed in future versions of Pandas, but using the `startrow` with version `1.4.2` worked for me. Try the following code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excelfilepath, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Núcleo de TRIAGEM', startrow=writer.sheets['Núcleo de TRIAGEM'].max_row, header=None)

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Núcleo de FALÊNCIAS', startrow=writer.sheets['Núcleo de FALÊNCIAS'].max_row, header=None)

df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RE - Triagem', startrow=writer.sheets['RE - Triagem'].max_row, header=None)

df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RE - Falências', startrow=writer.sheets['RE - Falências'].max_row, header=None)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Tried this but got "Exception has occurred: IndexError
At least one sheet must be visible"

Comment: This exception about visible sheet is risen when you try to close the file without actually writing data to it. You have something wrong in your code, maybe an exception before you get to the end.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future. Check your Pandas version if `if_sheet_exists='overlay'` is  not working. That was added to pandas in the version 1.4.0. Just try updating it.

Comment: I've tried in pandas 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 and no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Exactly, I've tried in pandas 1.4.0, and it's nor working.

Comment: tried with 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2 .. but not working

Comment: Guys, this only works with mode='a'

Comment: I've tried with 1.5.1 (in MacOs) but got the same problem, it just writes on top, doesn't append.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is missing. The intent of the overlay option is to write over the existing data, and not to append the new data below it.
The old data will in fact remain only for the part that was larger than the new one you're writing, or if you are **explicitly** setting *startrow* to a value high enough to write your new data below it.

As proposed already, you can do it like this :

```
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', startrow=writer.sheets['sheet1'].max_row, header=None)
```

This all becomes more obvious when you see that the initial name proposed for that option was *overwrite_cells* and not *overlay*.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by upgrading my version of pandas.

This requires you to first verify your version of pandas. You can do this by

```
print(pandas.__version__)
```

In my case, I was using pandas 1.3.5. I then ran

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

It then uninstalled the old version and installed the new version. Also, this did not work when I ran it as `sudo` or admin user.

Comment: It would be helpful to say to which pandas version you upgraded to and found working.

Answer (score 0):

We can write to excel by creating a utility function.

```
def save_excel_sheet(df, excel_path, sheet_name):
    if not os.path.exists(excel_path):
        df.to_excel(excel_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    else:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay', mode='a') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=writer.sheets[sheet_name].max_row, header=None, index=False)
```

and call the function like below

```
save_excel_sheet(df1, excel_path, sheet_name='Núcleo de TRIAGEM')

save_excel_sheet(df3, excel_path, sheet_name='RE - Triagem')
```

This will create a file if not exists and append to the provided sheet if the file exists.

**Pandas Version - 2.0.2**